# Backup failure after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: backup, gnupg

My computer was just upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 from 16.04. I have been having problem with the backup program. It appears that every time the backup program runs I get an error message and the backup program quits. The last backup was when I was using Ubuntu 16.04.

see the error message see below:

```
Error processing remote manifest (duplicity-inc.20181115T140641Z.to.20181122T185239Z.manifest.gpg): GPG Failed, see log below:
===== Begin GnuPG log =====
gpg: WARNING: "--no-use-agent" is an obsolete option - it has no effect
gpg: AES256 encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
gpg: decryption failed: Bad session key
===== End GnuPG log =====
```

Any help would be appreciated.
PLS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the information. I deleted all but one of the old backup files and move it to a new folder. Then I deleted all the old backup files (about 500gb). I started the backup process and surprise the backup program made a new backup. So your solution worked.
 -PLS

Answer (score 1):

Since no one provided any information yet:

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30318041/gpg-decryption-failed-bad-session-key) hints that the problem lies with the gpg version. Since I don't know how to change the gpg version duplicity/deja-dup (the backup tool and its graphical user interface) is using, I just deleted all old backups and started anew.

If the standard configuration is used this should work.

```
rm -rdf ~/deja-dup/*
```

Otherwise you can see the location under 'Storage location' in deja-dup.

*HINT:* Deleting backups is **bad**! But so is not being able to make new backups.
I hope this provides information for somebody to find a better solution!